# What happens to the rest of my RAM if I limit Windows to a lowered amount?

Tags: windows, memory

I've been experiencing a little bit of system instability, so right now I'm going about limiting my CPU and RAM usage within Windows to see if I can pinpoint anything. I've found how to limit CPU usage in Windows' power options, and it appears as if the old MS config Window has a place where you can limit the allowance of RAM that Windows has access to:
[image]

I have 8 GB of RAM installed and I'd like to limit it to 7. My question is, what happens to the excess 1 GB of RAM? Nothing at all? I have a dedicated video card and video RAM, will it affect that at all? Will this effectively guarantee that I never use more than 87.5% of my total RAM in Windows?

Overall, I guess what I'm asking is if this would be any sort of effective strategy to increasing system stability, or would it just make it more complicated? I am using Windows 8.1 (64-bit).

Comment: what would limiting your RAM accomplish?

Comment: If you want to have full control over the RAM, then I suggest a Mem Test or testing 1 stick at a time.

Comment: If you suspect hardware memory issues, then running a diagnostic such as Memtest86+ is a far more effective approach.  With your proposed scheme you would have no control of which locations of RAM to use, only the total size.

Answer (score 2):

> what happens to the excess 1 GB of RAM? Nothing at all?

Nothing happens to it. It just isn't used. In Task Manager, Windows will show a "Total" of 7168 MB in the system, and that's all it will use.

The unused RAM will still consume some power, as the refresh circuits have no way of knowing that some of the bits don't matter (anyway, it is not possible for bits in a RAM chip to be selectively refreshed).

Note that if you have just a single module with eight or sixteen chips, this would not result in one or two of the chips being unused. That isn't how RAM modules are organized.

> I have a dedicated video card and video RAM, will it affect that at all?

No. Video RAM is not counted in the RAM used by Windows memory management.

> Will this effectively guarantee that I never use more than 87.5% of my total RAM in Windows?

Not just "effectively". It WILL guarantee that.

> Overall, I guess what I'm asking is if this would be any sort of effective strategy to increasing system stability, or would it just make it more complicated? I am using Windows 8.1 (64-bit).

No, sorry. What is the nature of the instability you're seeing? Exactly what is the system doing, or not doing? Let's start with that. "Instability" could mean any of several things: BSODs, persistent application failures or hangs, whole-system hangs, ... what is the system doing?

If you think you have failing memory, then memtest86+ or the built-in memory test in Windows (Vista and later) should be tried. If you have more than one DIMM or SIMM, the best way to isolate memory errors to one module is to pull them one at a time, if your mobo permits that, and see if the instability persists (but expect the system to slow down, of course). If your motherboard doesn't permit that, or you only have one module, the only way to *really* know if a problem is due to a failing module is to try replacing it with a known good one.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing out of the ordinary that I know of happens.

If you set the limit to 7GB, Windows will only use up to 7GB. That doesn't mean that the same physical space in the DIMM (ram stick on your motherboard) is left alone. So if you had 2 x 2GB, and you limited Windows to 2GB, both DIMM's could be in use at the same time.

**Note: This may not be completely factual (it's what I've gathered from experience). If anyone has any evidence to suggest otherwise, please correct me.